# Module not found error with axios and follow-redirects in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, next.js13

I'm using Next.js version 13 with axios to make API requests in my application. When using getStaticProps() to fetch data from an API, I encountered a "Module not found" error related to the follow-redirects package. I have already installed axios, but the error persists. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  await axios.get('https://my-api-url.com/getlist')
    .then(response => {
      setData(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      setLoading(false);
    });

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}
```

I get the following error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'debug' in 'E:\resnxt\node_modules\follow-redirects'
Did you mean './debug'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, E:\resnxt).
If changing the source code is not an option, there is also a resolve option called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kinds of requests in the current directory too.

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/follow-redirects/debug.js
./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js
./node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs
./src/app/api/HomePageData.js
./src/app/page.js
```

I have already attempted reinstalling the follow-redirects package using the --save flag, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Any help or suggestions on resolving this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, you are using Next 13 App Router (`app` directory), but you are trying to fetch data via `getStaticProps` that isn't supported under the `app` directory. You may want to look through the migration docs - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#static-site-generation-getstaticprops

Comment: I am getting this same error. Using `"next": "13.2.4"`, but I am *not* using the `app` directory feature.

Comment: @BU0 you may want to post a separate question with stack trace and minimal repro illustrating your particular issue.